# Return Client information on Success payment PayPal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have successfully created developer Account on https://developer.paypal.com/
and add paypal button in my website, which redirect customers to paypal page and do the 
payment, now my problem starts from here, I need to automatically redirect client information 
back to my website on success payment by which I could track which customer do the payment.

On paypal button setting I have two urls (cancel and success) but it only redirect without any information and it only redirect when customer click on Back to Merchant button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem though [PayPal Auto Return Url](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside)

which redirected back to my site immediately after clicking the Pay button on the Payment Confirmation page with desire parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following [PayPal documentation page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/), which explains all of the HTML variables that can be set for your PayPal buttons.

You can set a value for `item_number` which is described as a "pass through variable" which is passed back to you when a payment is completed on your page, you could use this to track the payments to a specific user.

You can add this to your page by rendering something like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="AN ID YOU SPECIFY HERE" />
```

You can also use the `option_selection` variables (on1, on2 etc...) to add additional information to a payment.  These variable values are sent to you when you subscript to IPN (Instant Payment Notifications).